# run java file which depends on another java class

Tags: java, shell, centos

I have developed a java class (`A`) which calls another java class (`B`) and also uses external library `lib.jar`. all of the classes and jar files have been uploaded to /home/admin/ directory.

now I want to run class `A` on `centos`.

```
javac -cp /home/admin/lib.jar /home/admin/A.java /home/admin/B.java
```

and then:

```
java -cp /home/admin/lib.jar /home/admin/A.java
```

but it says: cannot find symbol: class B. how to solve the problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the directory `/home/admin` in the claspath:

```
java -cp /home/admin/lib.jar:/home/admin A
```

You also don't need to call `java` with the `A.java` file. You can call it with the class name `A` directly.